# Why is String? typed value inferred as Nothing?

Tags: kotlin

In the code below, why is `nullable` inferred as `Nothing?`, not `String?`?

```kotlin
fun main() {

    // nullable has nullable String type
    var nullable: String?

    // This is OK  
    nullable = null

    // notNull doesn't accept null values
    fun strLength(notNull: String): Int {                 
        return notNull.length
    }

    println(strLength(nullable))  // Throws a compiler error
}
```

compiler error message:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Nothing? but String was expected

Reproduce in [kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

---

I know if a value is assigned `null` on declaration, it is inferred as `Nothing?`.

```kotlin
val nullable = null  // type of nullable is Nothing?
```

`String?` and `Nothing?` seems to be incompatible types,
is my understanding wrong?

---

**Update**

After a few more exploring, it turns out my understanding
of kotlin types is wrong.

A `Nothing?` value can be assigned to a `String?` typed value:

```kotlin
val nullable: Nothing? = null
val maybeString: String? = nullable  // legal
```

but not some other nullable types

```kotlin
val nullable: Int? = null
// Type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but String? was expected
val maybeString: String? = nullable
```

So `Nothing?` is actually compatible with `String?`.

Comment: What you show in your update demonstrates how if you explicitly set the type to `Int?` at the variable declaration site, the compiler assumes you don’t want to use the specific type `Nothing?`. In your top example, the `String?` variable got smart-casted to the more specific `Nothing?` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null can be used as a `String?` or an `Int?` or any other nullable type because any of those types could have a null value. So null is very versatile.

Conceptually, `Nothing` works as the subtype of every non-nullable type, and `Nothing?` works as the subtype of every nullable type.

So the compiler here wants to match up your argument to a function that accepts some type that is nullable. Since it is looking for a match with any nullable type, it calls it the most versatile type, `Nothing?` even though you can’t specifically define a function that takes a nothing parameter.

And the error message is telling you it can’t find a function by that name that takes that kind of argument. And of course, the reason is that you specified that the argument to your `strLength` function must be non-nullable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my conceptual model on kotlin type was wrong. BTW, in the first line, is "Int?" mistyped as "Int"? @Tenfour04

Comment: Yes, typo! Fixed. The Nothing type is a weird one that is unlike how any other type works, since it conceptually is a subtype of everything even though multiple inheritance otherwise cannot exist in Kotlin. And you cannot possibly ever create an instance of it.